# How to revert conda updates when prompt meets unexpected error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have updated Spyder (`conda update spyder`) this morning using conda on Windows 8 and later when I checked I was unable to launch Spyder and Anaconda Navigator.

I tried updating the package again, but the prompt gave me the following warning and wasn't able to retrieve the package metadata:

```
WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained to only
using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, and
it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster
extractions.
```

Given that, I tried reverting the entire operation using `conda install --revision 9` (the previous revision), upon which I ran into the same warning message. This time, the prompt attempted to rollback, but it ultimately crashed with a lengthy report that finished with the following message:

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report. If submitted,
this report will be used by core maintainers to improve future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

Attempting either `conda update conda-build` and `conda remove conda-build` as suggested by the prompt incurs in the exact same error.

How can I restore my environment since conda locks me inside an error whenever I perform an operation to revert or remove something?

If it helps, this is all that changed in the environment with the update:

```
2019-07-03 10:40:00  (rev 10)
 ca-certificates  {2019.3.9 (conda-forge) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
 certifi  {2019.3.9 (conda-forge) -> 2019.6.16 (conda-forge)}
 conda  {4.6.14 (conda-forge) -> 4.7.5 (conda-forge)}
 cryptography  {2.5 (conda-forge) -> 2.7 (conda-forge)}
 krb5  {1.16.2 (conda-forge) -> 1.16.1}
 libssh2  {1.8.0 (conda-forge) -> 1.8.2 (conda-forge)}
 openssl  {1.0.2r (conda-forge) -> 1.1.1b (conda-forge)}
 pycurl  {7.43.0.2 -> 7.43.0.2}
 pyqt  {5.6.0 (conda-forge) -> 5.9.2 (conda-forge)}
 qt  {5.6.2 -> 5.9.7}
 sip  {4.18.1 (conda-forge) -> 4.19.8 (conda-forge)}
 spyder  {3.3.4 (conda-forge) -> 3.3.5 (conda-forge)}
 spyder-kernels  {0.4.4 (conda-forge) -> 0.5.0 (conda-forge)}
+conda-package-handling-1.3.10 (conda-forge)
+libarchive-3.3.3 (conda-forge)
+lz4-c-1.8.3 (conda-forge)
+python-libarchive-c-2.8 (conda-forge)
+xz-5.2.4 (conda-forge)
+zstd-1.3.3 (conda-forge)
```

Comment: By the way, you can use the command `conda config --set report_errors true` to send the error reports automatically to the developers

Comment: I [raised an issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8876) for the developers. If you are interested, keep an eye there. I will get back when I solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fix, update your conda environment also and reset spyder kernals

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
conda remove spyder-kernels
conda install spyder-kernels=0.*
```

**OR**

As a workaround
On thing i can suggest is, list down all the conda revisions, this is similar to restore points in your conda environment

```
conda list --revisions
```

Later, try to roll back to the previous version which you think was working fine.
example

`conda install --revision 35`

Comment: `conda install --revision 9` was already attempted as I mentioned above. My problem is that this environment now does not accept any sort of modification now. `conda update` fails for any package and also `conda remove` runs into the same "unexpected error" mentioned above and is unable to find the cause for it.

Comment: Do this delete .condarc file in your home or root directory

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [this was solved in the latest version of conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8876#issuecomment-512929690). You just need to update it using

`conda update conda -c conda-canary`

I haven't had the chance to try it myself - I'm working on a project and I don't want to break anything until I am done with it. However, I will give it a go after I am done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Am sharing the steps that worked for me. 
Please consider changing the environment to `root/base`. You can check all the available environments using `conda env list`. If it shows `base` as one of the environments, consider activating the environment using `activate base` or `source activate base`.

After activating the environment, all the conda commands started work. It even helped to install new packages and create new environments.